# how to create custom npm react component and use it in another react app like "react-dropdown-select"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, publish

I have a react application say (List students with react components and its own css ) this is standlone application which has its own . Now this react base / main component has to be attached in another react  application  say(library application ) on which one tab while clicking should render the student list.

Here there are two teams who manages student list app and library app. So in order to hand shake the students list has to b published to artifactory and then used in library app just like using another react npm component like react-dropdown-select / fadein / fadeout component.

However when i publish to artifactory it uses babel and transpiles the code to plain js and not react component anymore.
So i would like to know if there is a way to access the build bundles js files in library app. or is there any separate of doing component based integration.

Comment: its better to build a simple demo app that is trying to achieve what you are trying to do - a custom react component - and then, put relevant code where you think you are going wrong, and may be, put that component in a code sandbox or GitHub repo. right now, this seems like a vague question with no specifics for which community cannot give a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `babel/preset-react` and add it to config?

Installation (shell): `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react`